# using moderncv, how can I get rid of an empty line below address

Tags: formatting, moderncv

I am using moderncv 2.0.0 2015-07-28 to build my resume, but I got an empty line below address, how can I get rid of it?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 
\moderncvstyle{banking} 
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry} 

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\firstname{XX} 
\familyname{XX} 
\title{Résumé}
\address{address1}{address2}
\mobile{(123) 687 1709}
\phone{(123) 753 3208}
\email{XXX@gmail.com}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


\begin{document}
\makecvtitle % Print the CV title
```

The output is [image]

How can I remove the empty line between address1-address2 and the contact information?